# How to remove last element from a list in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm a beginner in dart.

```
void main() {
  var abf = '+37.4054-122.0999/';
  var abf2;
  abf2 = abf.replaceAll("+"," ");
  var abf1 = abf2.split(RegExp('(?=[+-])'));
  print (abf1[0]);
  print (abf1[1]);
}
```

The above code splits abf into two values for me
I want to remove the ending '/'. I tried many split methods using other variables but it's not removing the '/' even though its removing the '+'.

Answer (score 1):

Dart's `List` class has a built-in [`removeLast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/List/removeLast.html) method. Maybe you can try to split the string and then removing the last element:

```dart
String str = "str";
String newStr = str.split(''). removeLast().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do with the split.

But if you're looking the remove the `/` this should work:

```dart
String number = '+37.4054-122.0999/';
number = number.replaceAll("/"," ");
```

Comment: abf is a coordinate. So I'm splitting it into two (for latitude and longitude) while also keeping the symbols along with it. I just want to remove the slash at the end which is automatically created from the file for no reason

Answer (score 0):

You can create substring from this while you like to remove last element.

```dart
  String abf = '+37.4054-122.0999/';

  final result = abf.substring(0, abf.length - 1);
  print(result);
```